# Creation of orders in admin area

Tags: magento2.2.4, magento-2.2.5

- When trying to create an order for an existing customer get the error:

> Order saving error: Public hash should be defined

Where should define this?

---

Payment method enabled is Payflow Pro only.

When select first option gives issue.
When is added all details of credit card in second option order is stored and payment is charged.

[image]

Log for reference:

```
[2018-06-22 11:57:34] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Public hash should be defined
Trace: #0 vendor/magento/module-vault/Model/Method/Vault.php(473): Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault->attachTokenExtensionAttribute(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor))
#1 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php(82): Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), '6.65')
#2 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Processor.php(85): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\CaptureOperation->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#3 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(467): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#4 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(344): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#5 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/AbstractOperation.php(73): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice->capture()
#6 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php(30): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\AbstractOperation->invoice(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor))
#7 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Processor.php(85): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\CaptureOperation->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), NULL)
#8 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(467): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), NULL)
#9 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(448): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->capture(NULL)
#10 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(368): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->processAction('authorize_captu...', Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
#11 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(873): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->place()
#12 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(1062): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->_placePayment()
#13 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->place()
#14 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->___callParent('place', Array)
#15 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#16 generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->___callPlugins('place', Array, Array)
#17 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php(191): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->place()
#18 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(513): Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService->place(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
#19 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(406): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#20 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php(1922): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#21 vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save.php(49): Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create->createOrder()
#22 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save->execute()
#23 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 generated/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#30 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#33 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#35 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#37 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#38 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Please provide the complete details which you used in the order.

Comment: It might be the issue of payment method. Have you tried to place the order with different payment method?
Check your error log also.